# Can't login to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to log-in to MySQL server with PHPMyAdmin but it does not work,

I insert true `username` and `password` but it still doesn't work and I don't know what's the reason

**error:**

> mysql_real_connect(): (HY000/1045):Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost'(using password YES) Connection for control user as
>   defined in your configuration failed

can't enter to PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Share some more details, like is this on Lamp or wamp or what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111527/phpmyadmin-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no this may helpfull to you.

Comment: are you using linux distrubutor??

Comment: im using windows 10 and im using xampp

Comment: I have faced the same problem in my linux distributor and solved the problem given below my answer.
You just remove prefix sudo and try it.

Answer (score 4):

NEW Version of MYSQL does it this way.

In the new my-sql if the password is left empty while installing then it is based on the `auth_socket` plugin.

The correct way is to login to `my-sql` with **sudo** privilege.

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Enter your database password and then updating the password using:

```
$ ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new-password';
```

where `new-password` is your new database password or what you want

Once this is done stop and start the **mysql server**.

```
$  sudo service mysql stop
$  sudo service mysql start
```

Do comment for any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

After completion of any `.env` edit, must be clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`

If you fixed everything and still have an error then stop **XAMPP** and **restart** ***Apache*** and ***MySQL*** server