# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select <database and table> = BASE_TABLE ))

Tags: laravel, deployment, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have this error in gitlab CI console.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = <mydatabase> and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

after searching, I have already tried

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';
```

someone can help me please ? I use debian production server !

Comment: You can follow this instruction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57567218/cant-login-to-mysql-server/57567533#57567533

Comment: thanks a lot ! my problem is solved ! it was a problem of .env variable and I think of the cache as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new `my-sql` if the password is left empty while installing then it is based on the `auth_socket` plugin.

The correct way is to login to `my-sql` with **sudo** privilege.

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
```

if you are using the MAMP in macOS then the version of MAMP you're using installs itself in /Applications/MAMP. First make sure via the MAMP console that the Mysql server is on. Then connect like this from command line:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -uUsername -pPassword
```

Enter your database password and then updating the password using:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new-password';
```

where new-password is your new database password or what you want

then type the following the command in `my-sql` terminal:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

By trying this i hoped your issue will be solved if not then do comments
Thank you

Comment: Hi @Junaid, I am still facing same issue, it was working fine when I am running php7.4 but when I chaged 5.6 version then this is showing this error.